# Python - Remove watermark from pdf files

Tags: python, watermark, file-conversion

I created a simple script to convert rtf file to pdf. The script worked perfect, but I found it has watermark on each converted pdf file. I tried to use "watermark.remove()", it seems it doesn't work for my script.
Could anyone help me to take a look at it and let me know how to do it correctly. Thanks.

Here is my script:

```
import aspose.words as aw
import fnmatch
import os
import sys
import os,os.path
import comtypes.client

# load RTF document

source_path = "file_path"
dest_path = "output_path"

in_file = []  # save the source file to an array

for in_file in os.listdir(source_path):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(in_file,'*.rtf'):
        doc = aw.Document(source_path+in_file)
        out_name = os.path.splitext(in_file)[0]  # get file name only
        print (out_name) # print the file name


        doc.watermark.remove() #remove the watermark


        doc.save(dest_path+out_name+".pdf", aw.SaveFormat.PDF)
```

Comment: Where is the watermark coming from, was it on the RTF file already or is it being added by your PDF creation module?

Comment: If the watermark is generated by the module, there is likely some form of payment to remove it

Comment: The watermark is being generated by the module after converted the rtf file.

Answer (score 1):

The section "Licensing and Subscription" from the [documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/licensing/) says that (emphasis mine)

> The Trial version of Aspose.Words without the specified license provides full product functionality, **but inserts an evaluative watermark at the top of the document upon loading and saving** and limits the maximum document size to a few hundred paragraphs.

So you may consider purchasing the license or request a 30-day temporary license.